# W3C error: document type does not allow element X here; missing one of Y start-tag

Tags: javascript, html, w3c-validation

In my HTML/PHP code I have the following piece of code which makes sure the filtering is removed from a group of fields with JavaScript.

```
<form id="prices" action="">
<div class="box searchPrices" id="pricesDiv">
    <h2>Prijzen
    <p class="removeAll" rel="prices"></p>
    <span></span>
    </h2>
    ...
    </div>
</form>
```

This works as expected, but now my W3C validation is not validating correctly anymore. Is there a nice way to go around this caveat to make sure it validates nicely and still removes the filtering?

The W3C error I get:

> document type does not allow element "p" here; missing one of "object", "applet", "map", "iframe", "button", "ins", "del" start-tag

Comment: Paragraphs are not allowed in headings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HTML4:**

You're recieving an error because it isn't valid mark-up. You can't include `<p>` tags inside `<h2>` tags.

You can however, use elements such as `<span>` inside heading tags as they are inline.

Take a look at the relevant specification section [**here**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.5) - navigate around and you'll find which elements are allowed where etc (basically, all entities under the [**special**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html#special) section).

---

**HTML5:**

As of HTML5, **It is still invalid** to have [**paragraphs inside**](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/common-models.html#common.elem.phrasing) heading tags, according to the [**HTML5 specification**](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/h2.html#h2).

Comment: I can't see the `<p>` tag in the HTML5 list of phrasing elements you linked?

Comment: @Bergi Apologies, that was a fail and a half

Comment: Ok, I am trying to restructure my code to be correct. Problem I run into now is that my markup completely messed up by this change of course.. Thanks for making it clear though with the links!

Comment: @Hugo: According to W3 Validator, it was messed up *before* ;-)